# $S_3$ acts on itself by conjugation. Find $orbit((1 2))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Using the definition of orbit,

$Orbit((1 2)) $

$ = \{ \tau \cdot (1 2) \in S_3: \tau \in S_3 \}$

$ = \{ \tau(1 2)\tau^{-1} : \tau \in S_3\}$

I can now find the $orbit$ of $(1 2)$ by putting in every element in $S_3$. But is there a quicker way of finding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are $6$ elements of $S_3$ the problem is not so large.

Note that $(12)(12)(21)=(12)$ so that if $\sigma = \tau (12)$ then $\sigma (12)\sigma^{-1}=\tau (12) \tau^{-1}$

And $\sigma (12) = \tau$

Hence the elements of $S_3$ can be paired off into three pairs - elements of each pair have the same effect.

So you can test three elements instead of six.

You can also note that conjugation preserves cycle type, so the only possible elements of the orbit are $(12), (23), (31)$.

But I suspect that this exercise is set to help you to get an intuition about such things before proving a general theorem that all elements of the same cycle type in $S_n$ are conjugate to each other.